# Jdbcrowset bug ? return nullpointer exception!

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

```
package CrimeFile;

import com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sql.rowset.JdbcRowSet;

/**
 *
 * @author singgum3b
 */
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // TODO code application logic here
                    JdbcRowSet jrsi=new JdbcRowSetImpl();
                    jrsi.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=CrimeFile");                    
                    jrsi.setUsername("sa");
                    jrsi.setPassword("hellokitty");
                    jrsi.setCommand("select * from dbo.Target");
                    jrsi.execute();
        }              
        catch (SQLException ex) {            
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.ALL, null, ex);
        } 
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.prepare(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:666)
    at com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl.execute(JdbcRowSetImpl.java:553)
    at CrimeFile.test.main(test.java:30)
Java Result: 1
```

(line 30 is **crsi.excute();**)

I'm using sql server 2008 and ms jdbc 3.0.I googling around and found out this code is the same as in Sun's example [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/JdbcRowSet.html) .Am i wrong?

Comment: have you tried another, very simple table? Because while I don't have MS SQL I tried substantially the same code with MySQL driver, and no problems. Also, which JRE are you running?

Comment: i tried it on a test table with merely 1 column,but that seem no difference.I'm using jre 6.Further more it's seem to be jdbc driver problem,since here [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/rowset/JdbcRowSetImpl.java#JdbcRowSetImpl.execute%28%29)

Comment: Is it an option to try the open source jtDS driver?

Comment: thank a lot! this clearly a MS JDBC bug, i switched to jtDS driver and thing move swiftly.Please make the answer, since a can't post answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer was to switch to JtDS driver, which can be found [here](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)

There's clearly something bollixed up in MS JDBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and came to conclusion that the problem is that Microsoft driver doesnt support combination of `conn.prepareStatemen(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);` as stated 
[at microsoft website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378405.aspx)
resulting in exception of prepare() method.
I took source code from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/com/sun/rowset/JdbcRowSetImpl.java) created my own `MyJdbcRowSetImpl` and changed parameter of `prepareStatement` to `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE`

Jtds driver wasnt solution as it doesnt support rowsets.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this NullPointerException happening to me but only if I call execute() when I should NOT be doing so i.e. when using JdbcRowSetImpl with a ResultSet as argument

```
private JdbcRowSet executeWithResultSet(Connection conn, String sqlQuery)
        throws SQLException {
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
    JdbcRowSet jdbcRs = new JdbcRowSetImpl(rs);
    jdbcRs.execute(); //<-- results to the error as reported

    return jdbcRs;
}
```